# Кaк построить грaфик нa js, если я не знaю сколько у меня знaчений в итоге будет?

Tags: javascript, json, диаграммы

Мне нужно построить линейный грaфик нa js, но я не знaю сколько у меня в итоге будет дaнных. Кaкую библиотеку для этого посоветуете? И если можете, то дaйте пример постройки обычного линейного грaфикa учитывaя то, что мы не знaем кол-во дaнных.

Comment: так вы хотите "достраивать" график, пока данные грузятся? Просто для меня выглядит это так - график для данных х1 y1 x2 y2 (известны) построен, а затем динамически обновляется с данными x3 y3 x4 y4 (которые пришли спустя 5 минут)

Answer (score 1):

Этих библиотек уже столько, что тут каждый может по одной предложить и не повториться.

Я советую для начала изучить документацию [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). Вот [пример](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html), который Вам подойдет. Для построения простых графиков и диаграмм самое оно. Менее чем за час изучается.

К "простым" можно также отнести [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), но дизайн у них кондовый и неприятный, хотя на вкус и цвет...

Если потом что-то посложнее придется построить, то лучше изучить [D3.js](https://d3js.org/). Это, наверное, самый гибкий инструмент для визуализации данных на JS.